# Chromedriver: How to obtain login session for later bypass of login in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code does a curl to get a login session token to a website.

I then want to store the details of the session so that I can then use chromedriver to launch the dashboard page of the website without needing to login again.

Is there a way to reuse the token in the ChromeDriver object?

Answer (score 0):

When you're saying session token, you're actually referring to cookies.
You can save the cookies of the current ChromeDriver session by using `driver.manage()` to handle cookies, save them on file, access them by name or adding them to the current ChromeDriver instance. It is explained pretty well [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/cookies/).

Comment: Ok but what if my driver is not setup before I do the curl.

Comment: You didn't even mention cURL in the question, and you tagged the post with "selenium" and "python".

Comment: Read it again "My code does a curl to get a login session token to a website."     I know this is stackoverflow but its nice to be nice

Comment: You're right, I can't help you then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library in place of curl.

```
import requests

post_url = 'http://example.com/login'
payload = { 'key' : 'value' }
headers = {}

cookies_before = set(session.cookies.get_dict().items())

response = session.post(post_url, data=payload, headers=headers)

cookies_after = set(session.cookies.get_dict().items())

cookies_set = cookies_after - cookies_before
```

At this point `cookies_set` contains `key`, `value` tuples. You could use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to serialize the data if required.

Afterwards you can add the cookie information to the webdriver's browsing context.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://www.example.com/404')

for t in cookies_set:
     key, value = t
     driver.add_cookie({'name': key, 'value': value})
```